# Laravel Receipt items add

Tags: php, laravel, invoice, receipt

I'm using `laraveldaily/laravel-invoices` to generate invoices.

Here in the docs, the item was added manually.

```
$items = [
    (new InvoiceItem())->title('Service 12')->pricePerUnit(92.82),
    (new InvoiceItem())->title('Service 13')->pricePerUnit(12.98),
];
```

**But, if I have 10 or more products then how can I add items using foreach loop or any other way?**

```
$items = array();
foreach($products as $product)
{
    $items = [
    (new InvoiceItem())->title('Service')->pricePerUnit(92.82),
  ];
}
```

**It's not working.** **How Can I do this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you wrote your loop, you just set the array on each loop. You need to push each element:

```
foreach($products as $product) {
    $items []= (new InvoiceItem())->title('Service')->pricePerUnit(92.82);
}
```